# Query on KeyProperty's parent/ancestor

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

Is it possible to query based on the ancestors (parent) of a KeyProperty?

EG, something like the following:

```
class Foo(ndb.Model):
    bar = ndb.KeyProperty()

Foo.query().filter(Foo.bar.parent == some_key)
```

That is, I want to find all foos which have a bar key where the parent of the bar key is some_key.

I want to avoid having to store the parent of `bar` as a separate key property if that is possible. Basically I want to do an ancestor query on the KeyProperty, but couldn't see how you could do that, if it was possible at all.

My current solution is to use a ComputedProperty to extract the parent of bar and store it as a separate field. This works, but it seems unnecessary because I'm already storing the parent key as part of the bar key.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this is called an ancestor query:

```
Foo.query(ancestor=some_key)
```

UPDATE:

After conversation in the comments, we cleared up the desired result. A query will only work if the property in question is indexed. You could index parents by using a computed property and querying on it's value. Since `.parent()` will return a key, this should not be an issue:

```
class Foo(ndb.Model):
  bar = ndb.KeyProperty()
  bar_parent = ndb.ComputedProperty(lambda self: self.bar.parent())

Foo.query(Foo.bar_parent == some_key)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want to query on the Bar KeyProperty's ancestor, not the Foo object's ancestor. That is, I want to find all Foos which have a key property called bar which has some_key as an ancestor (or even just as the parent of bar).

Comment: My apologies, I should have read closer. This is not really possible and is essentially equivalent to a wildcard text search since keys are serialized from their pairs to a base64 safe value.

Comment: Thank you. I guess I'll just have to store the extra data for the parent.

Comment: Yes unfortunately. If you have a good idea of the key structure you could make a custom model to store such keys and then just use a `StructuredProperty`. Doing queries like `Foo.bar.parent` will work just fine with structured properties.

Comment: @Dylan Why did you accept this answer, when it doesn't answer your question?

Comment: @NickJohnson We did come to an answer in the comments (that it isn't possible without storing more data). If you know otherwise, please let us know! The Answer has been updated to reflect it now.

Comment: I'm fairly sure you could actually do this without a custom property, by doing an inequality query on the key property.